# Add QQuickView element to existing window

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I am trying to add an element to my window each time a button is clicked in C++ with QTQuick.

**I have a C++ class:**

*customclass.cpp*

```
void CustomClass::clicked() {
    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:///box.qml"));

    QObject *rectangleContainer = (QObject*)findItemByName(DownloadManager::rootObjects, "rectangle");

    // view.setParent(rectangleContainer); Does not work ?
    view.setProperty("visible", "true");
    view.show();
}
```

**and two qml files:**

*main.qml*

```
import com.acidic.customclass 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    CustomClass {
        id: demo
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        objectName: "rectangle"
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "#ffffff"
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Button")
        onClicked: {s
            demo.clicked();
        }
    }
}
```

*box.qml*

```
Item {
    Text {
        id: text1
        text: qsTr("Box!")
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
}
```

*The code has been shortened but it still should be enough to show my current state.*

`CustomClass::clicked` is indeed called when the button is clicked, but my aim is to create an instance of `box.qml` and insert it as a child to the `rectangle` element inside `main.qml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c++ backend is not needed, this is directly doable in qml with javascript.

You can use `Qt.createComponent()` in a Javascript to add dynamic objects.

Create and add a javascript resource (`componentCreation.js`), this script first creates the component from *`box.qml`* with `Qt.createComponent()`, then use the `createObject()` to attach  that new component as a child to the `"rectangle"` element:

`componentCreation.js` code:

```
var component;
var box;

function createBoxObject() {
    component = Qt.createComponent("box.qml");
        box = component.createObject(rectangle, {"x": 100, "y": 100});
}
```

Thats all, Import the javascript in main.qml, also call the script in the button     `onClicked`:

```
import com.acidic.customclass 1.0
import "componentCreation.js" as MyScript

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    CustomClass {
        id: demo
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        objectName: "rectangle"
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "#ffffff"

    }

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Button")
        onClicked: {
            MyScript.createBoxObject();

        }
    }
}
```

Note: I added box.qml to resources for direct access.
The created object will become a child of the rectangle object in main.

Comment: is this answer applicable for C++?

Comment: @Acidic, your button is in the qml window, this is directly implemented in QML, you can however use c++ with some additions

Comment: ah i see, i am very new to qt, i didn't know about the ability to use javascript with qml

Comment: @Acidic, Indeed its very handy, you don't need c++ backend for such work

Comment: @Acidic, to add the javascript, under _resources_ Add new, select `Qt`, and `JS File`

Comment: @MohammadKahan, I'm opening QT ide to try this now. Is the JavaScript run as a Script (like normal JavaScript) during runtime, or is it somehow compiled when you build your program?

Comment: @Acidic, hmm, all QML is interpreted not only javascript!

Comment: I don't quite understand how the created box in JavaScript is assigned as a child to the rectangle

Comment: @Acidic,  you pass `rectangle` as argument, to `createobject()`

Comment: Ah I see, so the `rectangle` argument is the ID of the QML element, correct?

Comment: @Acidic, exactly, you can add the box to any element by its `id`